# Scaling an Image with the Image tiff and x/y resolution

Tags: java, scale, resolution, dpi

I've got an issue with scaling the tiff images to their original size
if just the DPI resolution of the x and y axes are given. Could you
please point me to a How-To or explain it?

x resolution: 203 DPI
y resolution: 98 DPI
The tiff image is a byte[]

If you want to give me an example: I'm using Java.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's impossible without further info.

Comment: Which Info do you need?

Comment: You'll have to know how many dots you have in x and y ... if you cannot find that out, you can only make educated guesses.

Comment: Okay wait a sec, I'll edit :)!

Comment: After edit: What unit is this? pixels? dots per inch? In what form do you have the image? byte[] or ImageObject ...

Comment: DPI and it is a byte[], edited it - thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to decode it and display in any size?

Comment: Do you know about JAI? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html